# React router dom is not working in the main app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

Good morning,

I am having an issue when working with React router dom using my own webpack configuracion. I know using create-react-app will solve (almost) any issues and is friendly to use, but we would like to have more flexibility.

This is my main application:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from '../pages/Login'
import { AppContextProvider } from '../context/AppContext'

const MainApp = () => {
    return (
        <AppContextProvider>
            <Router basename={'nynweb'}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </AppContextProvider>
    )
}


export default MainApp
```

As you can see, it´s very simple. If I use localhost:3000/nynweb in the browser, it works perfectly and the router redirects to the login page. Then, If I type localhost:3000/nynweb/login, it should do exactly the same (at list to my understanding), but it doesn´t. I have the Cannot GET /nynweb/login response instead.

Internally the routing is working, though. I mean, when in the components I use the useHistory push method, it redirects properly (history.push('/login')).

What am I missing? Below I am posting my webpack configuration. Maybe the problem lies there:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const BabelRules = {
    test: /\.(js)$/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
}

const CSSRules = {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}

const ImageRules = {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'static/fonts/',
            },
        },
    ],
}

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/nynweb/',
        clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [BabelRules, CSSRules, ImageRules],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
    ],
}
```

Below I have included a screenshot with the applicacion tree, so that you can see where the static folder is located (all the assets lie there)

[image: Application tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation of Webpack states](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/), the `publicPath` option allows to serve **assets**, like images, SVGs etc. What's probably going on is Webpack searching for an asset with the name 'login', but can't find it.

I'd advise you to change this string to your public folder where you store assets (typically, /public).

Also, the example in [React-Router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) adds a forward slash before the `basename` string.

### Clarifications

You set your publicPath variable to `/nynweb/`, and what Webpack understands is that **everything under the '/nynweb/*' path is to be served as an asset**.

Change it to, let's say, `/nynweb/public/`, and now, **everything under the '/nynweb/public/*' path is to be served as an asset**.

Routes that are not '/nynweb/public/some_route' will now work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Gaëtan, but none of the assets I am using has the name login. I also tried to add a leading slash to the basename string but didn´ work either.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying, since you don't have an asset named "login", Webpack cannot GET it. Webpack acts **before** React-router. I'll update my answer to make things clearer.

Comment: Ok, understood now. I thought that the publicPath option was only considered when publishing the app, not in development stage.

Comment: Glad I could help! I hate to ask for it, but if it resolved your issue, please mark my answer as accepted. If not, I'll gladly help further!

Comment: I tried what you suggested and still didn´t work. I think that the publicPath in the module.exports section does not refer to the assets, because this is done within the rules. Please have a look, for example, to ImageRules object, and then you will see that its publicPath property is pointing to the assets path indeed.

Comment: The `publicPath` does indeed refer to the assets, the documentation states it explicitely. What is wrote within the rules is the specifications as how to treat a specific file. For instance, for your ImageRules object, it would be "**load every file from "publicPath" with an extension that matches "test" with the loader "files-loader", and output them in "static/fonts/"**". Can you show a tree of your project?

Comment: Well, I think that now I have really understood. So the publicPath applies to all the rules. I will try to fix this, thank you. What I wanted to do when I set the publicPath was to tell react that the app is hanging from there. I mean, if publicPath was set to 'nynweb', what I expected was to access to the application typing http://localhost:3000/nynweb. Then, I could (that was my idea) set all the routes through the react router dom. This might be my confusion. So... how can achieve this then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233163/discussion-between-gaetan-boyals-and-alberto).